# Why does the Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob UploadTextAsync method raises an exception, while the Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob one don’t?

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-storage, azure-storage-account, blobstorage, azure-sas

We have some legacy code that uploads strings to blobs in an Azure Storage Account, using the old `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob` library. The new version of the code uses the newer `Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob` library. Both the library provide the `CloudBlockBlob.UploadTextAsync` method, that lets you to upload a string directly to a blob. The two different versions of our code (the legacy one and the new one), are exactly the same and use the following instruction:

```
await new CloudBlockBlob(new Uri(string.Format("[SAS]", "[blobName]"))).UploadTextAsync("[content]");
```

where `[SAS]`, `[blobName]` and `[content]` are just placeholders; in production:

- `[SAS]` is replaced by our Azure Storage Account’s SAS.
- `[blobName]` is replaced by the name of the blob to create.
- `[content]` is replaced by the content of the blob.

Running the legacy version (the one using the `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob` library), everything works fine, but running the new version (the one using the `Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob` library) raises a `Microsoft.Azure.Storage.StorageException`, saying `'The specified resource does not exist.'`. Nothing has been changed in the Azure Storage Account, the network we use is the same, and so the SAS. What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was caused by the presence of `&amp;` inside the SAS in the legacy project. The legacy code used `cscfg` files, since the old Azure Cloud Services technology was used. The new one, instead, uses `appsettings.json` and the new .NET Worker Services template. In this case, to read the configuration, I made it work removing the `&amp;`.